# why https method put and delete

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, restlet

I am not expert in REST architechture and I am going through the tutorials. I have a confustion in understanding the role of http methods. What I have understood is,there are four HTTP methods GET,POST,PUT,DELETE According to the tutorials it does the following job.

GET->Readonly Operation
POST-> create the resource
PUT->update the resource
DELETE->Deletes the resource

My doubt over here is, can I write a code for deleting a resource by annotating @POST instead of @DELETE ?
I have not used @PUT and @DELETE in my application rather I have used only @POST for doing this operation?
Is it really mandatory to use @PUT and @DELETE? what is the consequences if I dont use this?

```
@POST
@Path("/{empNo}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void deleteEmployee(@PathParam("empNo") String empNo) {
    EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(empNo);
}
```

Comment: One consequence is that everyone, including yourself maybe even, will get confused on what happens when calling the end points.

Answer (score 0):

From Roy Fielding dissertation about REST, he only mentioned about **uniform interface**.

So that you can define your uniform interface as you want.

POST->delete resource is ok

POST->update resource is ok.

But if you want to make your api more clearly and follow the HTTP standard.

-POST->create new object

-PUT->update object

-DELETE-> delete object

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET : to get information
@POST : to save information
@PUT : to update Information
@DELETE : to delete information
```

Above description is just a convention which is followed globally.

Taking your example

Ideally it should be

```
@DELETE
@Path("/{empNo}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void deleteEmployee(@PathParam("empNo") String empNo) {
    EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(empNo);
}
```

But this is also compleletely valid

```
@POST
@Path("/{empNo}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public void deleteEmployee(@PathParam("empNo") String empNo) {
    EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(empNo);
}
```

The only catch is its **not predictable** API. Might be confusing to start with.

Lets say a new guy need to work on Delete Employee.

First thing he will do is look for `@DELETE`

Comment: The only catch is that some HTTP methods can (or should) not have a request body and that `GET` calls can also be cached by your browser, so that if you use `GET` to delete resources, it might be invoked from cache rather than actually calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

We can use any method to do any job.

That means

```
@GET
can create new element, can get any element, can update and also delete


@POST
can create new element, can get any element, can update and also delete


@PUT
can create new element, can get any element, can update and also delete


@DELETE
can create new element, can get any element, can update and also delete
```

These method generally define how data will be send as request and limit of data that can be sent

```
@GET
only query string, which is browser URL with ?key1=value1&key2=value2...., Most webservers have a limit of 8192 bytes (8KB)

@POST
can send query string data(not preferred), data is sent in the request payload instead of in the URI. Default to 2MB. 

@PUT
same as POST

@DELETE
same as GET
```

If look into `Gmail`, `Facebook` `LinkedIn` other sites, they all use `POST` method to fetch new mails, messages, updates, notification and other things...

Using REST naming convention is to help user and new developer to give an idea what API will be doing.

On reading `GET` it will help user to know what API will be doing. Similarly for `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. To make it easy to understand REST define certain guidelines to follow. Not necessary, good to have.